# visual studioのbuildタブがない

Tags: visual-studio

お世話になります。
visual studio 2017を用いてc#のファイルをビルドしようととしたのですが、下図のようにビルドタブがないため、実行できません。
どうすればよいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

ビルド対象となるプロジェクトが読み込まれていません。ファイルメニューからプロジェクトもしくはソリューションを開きましょう。

なお、タブではなくメニューです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事ビルドできました。タブではなくメニューとのご指摘、ありがとうございます。